# Semantic UI & ReactJS, MeteorJS, infinite scroll not calling onBottomVisible() in visibility

Tags: meteor, reactjs, infinite-scroll, semantic-ui

UPDATE #1: as per the Answer below, this works in Safari but NOT Chrome on a MacBook Pro.
UPDATE #2: This issue is reproducible without Meteor as per the JSfiddle below w/ ReactJS and Chrome. However it NEVER works with Meteor, i.e. `react-packages` Atmosphere package unless 1) put Chrome into dev tools mobile device mode AND add this to index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
```

Semantic UI infinite scroll in ReactJS app not calling `onBottomVisible()` in `.visibility`. `onBottomVisible` never get's called when scrolling to the bottom of the page.

I tried forcing a `height` onto `<div className="myfeed">` but that only triggers the `onBottomVisible()` callback on load, not when scrolling to the bottom.

See the code below and these JSfiddle's:

- ReactJS version: http://jsfiddle.net/2wvfjpy9/9/
- Non-React version: https://jsfiddle.net/4p6d7x86/12/

**CSS:**

```css
.myfeed {
    height: 200px;
}
```

**ReactJS / JavaScript:**

```jsx
var App = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {
        $('.myfeed').visibility({
            once: false,

            // update size when new content loads
            observeChanges: true,

            // load content on bottom edge visible
            onBottomVisible: function() {
                console.log("infiniateScroll ... called.");    
                alert("infiniateScroll ... called.");    
          }
        });
    },

    render: function() {

        var showFeedHTML = [];
        for (var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
            showFeedHTML[i] = (
                <li key={ i }>
                    { i }: stuff
                </li>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className="myfeed">
                <h3>Semantic UI & ReactJS: Infinite Scroll Example</h3>
                { showFeedHTML }
            </div>    
            );
    }
});


React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working in Chrome on OS X, by adding `offset`. Only works on Chrome with a healthy offset. Value required seems to depend on how deeply the DOM element is nested.

Here's an update JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wvfjpy9/17/

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $('.myfeed').visibility({
        once: false,

        offset: 5, // Only works on Chrome with a healthy offset. 
                   // Value required seems to depend on how deeply 
                   // the DOM element is nested.

        // update size when new content loads
        observeChanges: true,

        // load content on bottom edge visible
        onBottomVisible: function() {
            console.log("infiniateScroll ... called.");    
            alert("infiniateScroll ... called.");    
      }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the css and it works just fine. I've added more records so you don't get confused by the height of JSFiddle javascript window. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q17w57ca/) edited JSFiddle.

```jsx
var App = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $('.myfeed').visibility({
      once: false,
      observeChanges: true,
      onBottomVisible: function() {
        console.log('infiniateScroll ... called.');
        alert('inifiniateScroll ... called.');
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {

    var showFeedHTML = [];
    for (var i=0; i < 100; i++) {
      showFeedHTML[i] = (
        <li key={ i }>
          { i }: stuff
        </li>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="myfeed">
        <h3>Semantic UI & ReactJS: Infinite Scroll Example</h3>
        { showFeedHTML }
      </div>    
    );
  }
});


React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[image: screen recording]

Comment: That's still not triggering `onBottomVisible()`, btw here's the JSfiddle link that works, yours had https, needs to be just http: http://jsfiddle.net/q17w57ca/

Comment: @GiantElk it works fine for me. did a quick screen recording [here](https://i.gyazo.com/f4f13f034b7fcb6e427802fc12d94ef1.gif)

Comment: Thanks for the screen recording. This works in my Safari browser by NOT in Chrome, on a MacBook Pro. Any idea why? I'm guessing Semantic UI needs to tweek their .visibility code for cross browser compatibility. Or maybe it's a jQuery version in the actual JSFiddle.

Comment: This JSfiddle has the latest versions of all dependencies, jQuery, React, Semantic UI. Still not working in Chrome. Strange that the non-React version does work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/q17w57ca/6/

Comment: It works in Chrome, only if I go into the Dev Tools and toggle device mode to mobile. I'll have to try this in a stand alone React App without JSfiddle.

Comment: weird, what version of Chrome do you use? I'm on `Version 44.0.2403.130`

Comment: I have Chrome `Version 44.0.2403.130 (64-bit)`. I got it working in Chrome without the mobile device mode, by resizing the CSS panel height and the JS panel width in JSfiddle window. But when you play with panel sizes it stops working and, now I closed Dev Tools and reopend I can't get it working again unless turn on mobile device mode.

Comment: why don't you try it in your React app?

Comment: I tried breaking it in Safari, but it's rock solid. Chrome shows these console errors when resizing JSfiddle code windows: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined

Comment: I will next, just wanted to narrow this down a bit more, re: `why don't you try it in your React app?`

Comment: OK, so in my ReactJS app this works in Safari, but I can NEVER get it working in Chrome, in spite of getting it working in JSfiddle in mobile device mode. With 1 exception, when my app 1st loads the <div> isn't populated from the DB, so the bottom is visible and triggers `onBottomVisible()` but never once the <div> is populated.

Comment: looks like your editing my Question, best to put the fix in your Answer. Thanks for your help so far, this is a whacky bug seems browser specific.

Comment: I narrowed this down to only if using Meteor and `react-packages`, I'm rewording the Question. I managed to get it working with Meteor and Chrome only if add this to my index.html, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />` and ONLY when in mobile device mode. So getting close, now need to get it working in regular Chrome browser.

Comment: Here's a github repo and bug description: https://github.com/giantelk/react-meteor-infinite-scroll-semantic-ui